# VB.NET Get direction from one point to another

Tags: vb.net, math, gdi+, trigonometry

I need this function to work in order to continue progress with my simple scrolling shooter game.

```
Public Function GetDirection(origin As Point, target As Point) As Single
    'do some trigonometry here
    Return Direction
End Function
```

Normally I would insert these parameters: `GetDirection(player_point, MousePosition)`

And use them in this context:

```
Dim direction As Single = GetDirection(player_point, MousePosition)
Dim blt_increment_x As Single = Math.Sin(direction)
Dim blt_increment_y As Single = Math.Cos(direction)
```

Now these variables can be used to move my bullet entity:

```
blt_point.X += blt_increment_x
blt_point.Y += blt_increment_y
```

All I need is the code for this `GetDirection()` function. Currently I have no idea where to start, and I set it to constantly return 0. I am using VB.NET. Thanks! :)

For those wondering, here's a screenshot of my game, very reminiscent of diep.io :)
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to calculate an angle? If so then it's simply Pythagoras with a bit of algebra. It's the sort of thing that you learn in primary school maths class. I suggest that you make an effort and then post what you've done if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Math.Atan2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb) method. I'm not a VB developer but I think you can convert following pseudo-code into VB:

```
direction = Math.Atan2(target.Y - origin.Y, target.X - origin.X)
```

But looking into your code and noticing that you will use `Math.Sin` and `Math.Cos` just in the next line, the whole idea makes very little sense. Direction of the movement is specified by differences in X and Y coordinates. If you want to have a constand speed, your code could be something like this

```
dX = target.X - origin.X
dY = target.Y - origin.Y 
len = Math.Sqrt(dX*dX + dY*dY)
blt_increment_x = Speed * dX / len
blt_increment_y = Speed * dY / len
```